Use JavaScript TradingView Widget in Blazor razor page, possible?
try to use Widget as it is from Trading View in test Blazor razor page. Chart appearing, but I can't change parameters in code, since compilator does not accept anything after src attribute as on the picture.
Screen
Is it possible to inject parameters, so I could change e.g. Symbol?
Thanks!
I also, tried to save JS code to separate file and call it like
 await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("./script/tv.js");
but nothing happened.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
